# Yii2 ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column?

Tags: php, yii2, oracle

В Yii2(с ActiveRecord) я питаюсь добавить большой текст в БД но вернет такая ошибка.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1461 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
>   (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:159)
>   The SQL being executed was: UPDATE "POST_CONTENT" SET text='длинный текст' WHERE id='79'

В таблице есть поля текст и её тип CLOB. Загуглил и смотрел много примеров они не помогает.
Помогите что мне делать?

Comment: текст обрамленный одинарными кавычками это варчар, а у него есть ограничения на длину. вместо SET text='длинный текст' используй SET text=TO_CLOB('длинный текст < 4000 символов') || TO_CLOB('длинный текст < 4000 символов') || ...

Comment: но в текст не меньше 4000 символов.....там целая HTML страница. и поэтому я указал тип CLOB

Comment: придется бить на куски, преобразовывать к клобу и конкатить клобы между собой. в оракле нет возможности запихнуть в запрос клоб.